# R - Comparing strings that are similar but not identical

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains the sender's name and/or sender's email address.

```
sender_info = c('Kelvin [mailto:kelvin0354@gmail.com]','Kelvin','Sheryl [mailto:sheryl@hotmail.com]','Sheryl <sheryl@hotmail.com>','Oscar',)
```

I want to check for the number of unique senders. As you can tell from sender_info, there are 3 unique senders - Kelvin, Sheryl and Oscar.

I tried implementing a couple of methods but they don't work. One of it involves the use of the levenshteinSim() function from the R RecordLinkage library to check for how similar each of the elements are. However, this method fails when the elements are too different (eg. 'Kelvin [mailto:kelvin0354@gmail.com]' and 'Kelvin').

I would really appreciate if anyone can give me a hint or two on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'd go about trying to standardise your strings. Break them into Name and Email and then compare them. Take at look at the many regex / regular expression questions on the r tag for some advice about extracting strings that fit a pattern - try `[r] [regex]` as a search on this site.

Comment: `gsub("[][<>]|mailto:", "",sender_info)` as a starter to clear out irrelevant bits.

Comment: @thelatemail Okay, I'll give it a try! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data structure is always like the mentioned sample, these codes would help:

```
    sender_info = c('Kelvin [mailto:kelvin0354@gmail.com]','Kelvin','Sheryl [mailto:sheryl@hotmail.com]','Sheryl <sheryl@hotmail.com>','Oscar')
    new_sender <- sapply(strsplit(sender_info, split = " "), "[[", 1)
    unique(new_sender)
    #[1] "Kelvin" "Sheryl" "Oscar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to `strsplit` is `str_split` from `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
unique(str_split(sender_info, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE)[,1])
# [1] "Kelvin" "Sheryl" "Oscar"
```